# inserting records from two different tables into a single table in oracle

Tags: oracle

I want to insert data from two different tables (say table A and table B ) into a third table (table C) in oracle.

I have written two different cursors for fetching data from table A and B separately, and populated two collections based on these two tables.

Now, i want to insert the data in those two collections into the third table (table C), how can i get this done.

Now there are two common columns that are present in both the columns, say for example ID and YEARMONTH, these two columns are there in all tables (A, B and C).

I have tried doing a merge based on these two fields.
but i am looking for an efficient and more convenient way to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't provide code you wrote, so I'll guess: *cursors* mean PL/SQL. If you're doing it in a loop, row-by-row, it'll be slow-by-slow.

As there are common columns in both tables (A and B), I'd suggest doing it in pure SQL: join those two tables and insert the result into C. Something like

```
insert into c (id, yearmonth, ...)
select a.id, a.yearmonth, ...
from a join b on a.id = b.id;
```

Make sure that indexes exist on columns you use to join tables. Or, even better, compare explain plans in both cases (with and without indexes) and choose an option which seems to be the best.

Answer (score 0):

insert into tableC
select * from tableA where ...
union
select * from tableB where ...